Is there a better way of awake/sleep state automation in Google Home besides Hijacking an Aqara Light?
I got an Aqara FP2 sensor to monitor when I fall asleep and wake up.
All my automation runs on the Google Home/Assistant platform and I haven't found a way to access the sleep state from the sensor through the script editor
So I got an M1S Hub which has a nightlight I bind to the Sleep sensors state. The light is exposed in Google home and can be used.
However that feels very hacky.
Is there a better way to use the Sleep state in Google Home? Maybe IFTT or something?
I hoped I could use virtual devices with the M1S Hub somehow which both Aqara and Google can automate. Somehow bridging the gap with the hub, but I haven't found a good way yet.
